# Delphi XE6: How to enumerate RCData resource names?

Tags: delphi, embedded-resource, enumeration

I have embedded several resources into the executable, for instance language (text) files.

Below you can see the contents of `Languages.rc` file:

```
Language_English  RCDATA  Languages\English.ini
Language_German   RCDATA  Languages\German.ini
Language_Czech    RCDATA  Languages\Czech.ini
```

---

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8837439/1997354), which definitely helps, however I have rather hard time implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to get the list of those resources as a EOL-delimited string, then the first step would be defining `EnumRCDataProc` function:

```
function EnumRCDataProc(hModule: HMODULE; lpszType, lpszName: PChar; lParam: NativeInt): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  TStrings(lParam).Add(lpszName);
  Result := True;
end;
```

---

Once we have that done, we can get to work:

```
function EnumerateRCDataResourceNames: string;

var
  ExecutableHandle: HMODULE;
  ResourcesList: TStringList;

begin
  ExecutableHandle := LoadLibraryEx(PChar(Application.ExeName), 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
  try
    ResourcesList := TStringList.Create;
    try
      EnumResourceNames(ExecutableHandle, RT_RCDATA, @EnumRCDataProc, NativeInt(ResourcesList));
      Result := ResourcesList.Text;
    finally
      ResourcesList.Free;
    end;
  finally
    FreeLibrary(ExecutableHandle);
  end;
end;
```

---

Remarks:

- As is in the original answer (see question), it is not possible to use `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE` or `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE` as these types are no longer defined in Delphi XE6, at least AFAIK.
- You can, however, define those constants, according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx):

  - `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE` = `$00000040`
  - `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE` = `$00000020`

Comment: You can use those flags. If they aren't defined, then define them. The values are well known.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you for pointing it out. I hope I added the right values to my answer. Btw, is there any advantage for those constants over just using `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE`?

Comment: I don't know, I doubt it matters much

Comment: FWIW, the flags you mention are not defined in XE2 either. I doubt if they ever were, in (Winapi.)Windows.pas.